# JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'highcharts' in Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio-2012, highcharts

Hi I am a beginner to JQuery and Highcharts and running into problems I can't solve spending over 3-4 hours on it while following Highcharts documentation to create the first chart in Visual Studio 2013.

I create a barebone ASP MVC 5 application and add the following code to Index.cshtml body:

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container1" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>
```

Then I add the following code to _Layout.cshtml:

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script>$(function () {
    $('#container1').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Fruit Consumption'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Fruit eaten'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Jane',
            data: [1, 0, 4]
        }, {
            name: 'John',
            data: [5, 7, 3]
        }]
    });
});</script>
```

It output html code that immediate crash the IE browser launching from with Visual Studio, giving me error message: JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'highcharts' in Visual Studio

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Index - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    <link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script>$(function () {
    $('#container1').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Fruit Consumption'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Fruit eaten'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Jane',
            data: [1, 0, 4]
        }, {
            name: 'John',
            data: [5, 7, 3]
        }]
    });
});</script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Application name</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Home/About">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Home/Contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="/Account/Register" id="registerLink">Register</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Account/Login" id="loginLink">Log in</a></li>
    </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">




<h2>Index</h2>
<div id="container1" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>
<p>
    <a href="/BatteryLog/Create">Create New</a>
</p>

    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                Voltage
            </th>
            <th>
                Current
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

    <tr>
            <td>
                3.12
            </td>
            <td>
                3.18
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="/BatteryLog/Edit/21">Edit</a> |
                <a href="/BatteryLog/Details/21">Details</a> |
                <a href="/BatteryLog/Delete/21">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
            <td>
                3.124
            </td>
            <td>
                6.28
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="/BatteryLog/Edit/22">Edit</a> |
                <a href="/BatteryLog/Details/22">Details</a> |
                <a href="/BatteryLog/Delete/22">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>

        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; 2014 - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    //<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/respond.js"></script>



<!-- Visual Studio Browser Link -->
<script type="application/json" id="__browserLink_initializationData">
    {"appName":"Chrome","requestId":"bab8eaa5834742c0a90d4a2266b8953c"}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:19978/19d3f54454e64aa2aeab6fa68d1e8a88/browserLink" async="async"></script>
<!-- End Browser Link -->

</body>
</html>
```

However, if I copy and paste this into an static html file and open browser to view it offline from my desktop, then the charts works.

Please help! I spent hours already trying out different things to solve this! 
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are including jQuery twice. In the header:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and at the bottom of the page:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

This second inclusion will overwrite the first one, where Highcharts was attached to. I.e. inside the document ready callback, `$` refers to `jquery-1.10.2.js`, which doesn't have Highcharts added to it.

You are actually including both libraries, jQuery and Highcharts twice. Don't do that.

Comment: Then there is probably something else wrong in your code, in addition to this problem.

Comment: Wait. it works now! thank you! I forgot that // does not comment out second script

Comment: Right, HTML comments are `<!-- comment -->`.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case this helps anyone, this was happening for me when I was using AngularJS and mistakenly, a self closing ng-view tag. Angular ended up loading twice so if relevant ensure your ng-view tag is

```
<ng-view></ng-view>
```

instead of

```
<ng-view/>
```

Took a while to figure out, hopefully it will save somebody else time.